# Laravel 5.1 - Form: Method number does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I've just upgraded to Laravel 5.1 and i'm creating a simple form with "text" and "number" inputs. My problem came when i need to declare as numeric one of my input fields:

```
{!! Form::number('otp', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'OTP']) !!}
```

It outputs this error: Method number does not exist. In addiction, i don't see the section "Html and Forms" in the docs, it seems they removed it.

Does anybody had my same problem with Laravel 5.1?

Comment: http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#number

Comment: didn't know about this other docs, solved, thanks!

Comment: @LucaMormile please answer the question yourself then, so it can help others, and upvote the commend by pinkkal vansia.

Comment: my apologies, i'm new here and still don't know the rules here, how can i upvote his comment?

Answer (score 3):

You may use `{!! Form::input('number', 'otp', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems some rules are changed in 5.1, so to solve this, first update the composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
}
```

then the app.php file:

```
'providers' => [
   // ...
   Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
   // ...
],


'aliases' => [
   // ...
     'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
     'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
   // ...
],
```

Source: http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html